# MySQL: Renaming primary key

Tags: mysql

While creating table in mysql I've set wrong name to primary key column.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `old_id_name` `new_id_name` integer auto_increment primary key
```

After that I'm getting

```
Error message: Multiple primary key defined
```

So the question is how can I rename the column. Note that I don't want to change primary key to another but just rename it.

Comment: First you have to remove old primary key then you can alter table for new primary key.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, but that means that data in column will be lost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use query like this

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `old_id_name` `new_id_name` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

it will change only the column name of primary key

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column old_name new_name int;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad4a7)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

If your old column already contains `NOT NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` property just use it

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE column old_name new_name int;
```

or if you need to add `NOT NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` property use it

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE column old_name new_name int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```